# Website optimization - css and images

Tags: css, optimization, web

I'm in the process of optimizing a high traffic site.  The site I am working on has many widgets - say 20 or so and only 7 are loaded by default.  I was thinking of separating my css and image sprites for faster load times for the default widgets.

For the rest of the non-default  widgets, I was thinking of having a separate css file and image sprite for each and every one.  This way, when a user selects a non-default widget, I could dynamically inject the CSS file for that particular widget.

My question is - do you think this is OK to do or potentially worse for optimization since I would have more HTTP requests now since the non-default widgets would have their own css and image sprite files?  Obviously though, the file sizes now would be cut down too.

Thoughts?  Or anyone else who tackled the same issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> do you think this is OK to do or potentially worse for optimization since I would have more HTTP requests now since the non-default widgets would have their own css and image sprite files?

Well, in the end that's down to mathematics and something only you can answer :) It will depend on what the actual numbers look like.

Keeping the default widgets' sprites in one file sounds obvious from what you describe.

As for the non-default widgets, If you have the technical means to do so, you could try analyzing your usage statistics. Which of the non-default widgets are being used the most? Are there some that stand out strongly from the others in terms of requests? Then build one image with all the necessary sprites for those, and keep separate images for the rest.

Also take into consideration whether the cost-benefit ratio is really good. Working out and using CSS sprites can increase maintenance costs in the long term, as updating graphics becomes a more difficult task that it was before. Now reducing the number of requests is a very important optimization technique, but there are other factors as well. Maybe the time and money saved by not using sprites could be better used somewhere else, like in improving the site's usability or buying new RAM for the server.

Comment: True, this was one of my ideas as well - doing it based on usage statistics

Comment: Probably the most reliable way to go about it. Extracting the data from the statistics could be a bit of the pain but well worth the effort.